# Add prefix_with clause to insert of a particular class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I customize the `prefix_with` of each model class in SQLAlchemy such that each one can have a different insert statement?

I actually want the `OR IGNORE` clause added to some of the classes.

PS: I'm relatively new to SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 5):

The ORM doesn't have hooks into how it produces `insert()` constructs, so the best you can do here is intercept the `insert()` statements at the `Table` level, which is probably good enough here seeing as you want to do the "ignore" thing across the board for those tables, here's a recipe that uses a class decorator to make it generic.  We are making use of the [before_execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.before_execute) event here to rewrite certain `insert()` constructs:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import Insert

_ignore_tables = set()

@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_execute", retval=True)
def _ignore_insert(conn, element, multiparams, params):
    if isinstance(element, Insert) and \
        element.table.name in _ignore_tables:
        element = element.prefix_with("IGNORE")
    return element, multiparams, params

def ignore_inserts(cls):
    _ignore_tables.add(cls.__table__.name)
    return cls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class A(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'a'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @ignore_inserts
    class B(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'b'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @ignore_inserts
    class C(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'c'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(e)
    Base.metadata.create_all(e)

    s = Session(e)

    s.add_all([A(), B(), C()])
    s.commit()
```

Having it across the board like that would make me nervous, here's a different version so that you can use a context manager to set up the rule for specific tables with a specific `Session`:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import Insert
from contextlib import contextmanager

@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_execute", retval=True)
def _ignore_insert(conn, element, multiparams, params):
    if isinstance(element, Insert) and \
        'ignore_tables' in conn.info and \
        element.table.name in conn.info['ignore_tables']:
        element = element.prefix_with("IGNORE")
    return element, multiparams, params


@contextmanager
def ignore_inserts(session, names):
    conn = session.connection()
    info = conn.info   # hold onto info so we can still
                       # get to it when the Connection is closed
    previous = info.get('ignore_tables', ())
    try:
        info['ignore_tables'] = set(names)
        yield
    finally:
        info['ignore_tables'] = previous

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class A(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'a'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class B(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'b'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class C(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'c'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(e)
    Base.metadata.create_all(e)

    s = Session(e)

    with ignore_inserts(s, ['b']):
        s.add_all([A(), B(), C()])
        s.commit()

    with ignore_inserts(s, ['a', 'c']):
        s.add_all([A(), B(), C()])
        s.commit()
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for that! Just an note for SQLite, `IGNORE` should probably be `OR IGNORE` as per https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html.

Comment: after ten years, how can this not be in sqlalchemy by now