# SQL Alchemy: SAWarning: Identity map already had an identity for (<class >), replacing it with newly flushed object

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am using SQLAlchemy with MySQL to insert rows into a DB table. On some occasions I might try to insert the same row again, which is why I have an event listener for the `before_execute` event, whose point is to prevent OnDuplicateKey exceptions. The listener looks like this:

```
# Intercept calls for Insert and add IGNORE to the generated SQL
@event.listens_for(Engine, 'before_execute', retval=True)
def _ignore_insert(conn, element, multiparams, params, execution_options):
    # Check that this is an Insert call, and that the current Insert call is meant for a table which we want to add
    # the IGNORE keyword to
    if str(conn.engine.url).startswith('sqlite'):
        # Avoid generating illegal SQL syntax for sqlite DBs
        return element, multiparams, params
    if isinstance(element, Insert) and 'ignore_tables' in conn.info and element.table.name in conn.info[
        'ignore_tables']:
        element = element.prefix_with('IGNORE')
    return element, multiparams, params
```

The implementation for the wrapper was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579232/4259027)

This wrapper works perfectly, but every time I try to insert a row that already exists in the DB, a Warning will be thrown:

```
SAWarning: Identity map already had an identity for (<class 'Store.PipetorDiagnostics.PipetorDiagnostics'>, (0,), None), replacing it with newly flushed object.   Are there load operations occurring inside of an event handler within the flush?
```

99% of the time I can safely ignore this warning, because after I store an object, I don't need to read from it again in the same SQLAlchemy session.

But there is a rare occasion where I do want to read the object again, and if I try to read from it, I will receive the following exception:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.ObjectDeletedError: Instance '<PipetorDiagnostics at 0x1c81c8effd0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
```

Looking closer at the session itself, and the `identity_map` property, it looks like even if I store a very large number of rows that already exist (even more than 500 rows), only **one** of those rows will have this warning thrown for, and only **one** will be unavailable, I can observe that by looking at the `identity_map` and see that just that one object which had the warning thrown for, appears in the `identity_map._dict` property.

Of course, if I check if the row exists in the DB before attempting to store it (thus avoiding the commit of rows that already exist), no warning is thrown at all, but such a check is very costly, so I would like to continue to use my wrapper, without the warning and exceptions occurring.

Any idea why this might happen, and how to avoid it? I already tried using `session.refresh()` but that also throws an exception, same for `session.merge()`. `session.expunge()` and `session.flush()` don't do anything in this scenario.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Angel I did not manage to find a solution, at the moment I just make sure to not store duplicate objects if I know that I will need to use their data in the current session. Otherwise I just let the DB handle the duplicates and ignore the errors (not great but without a solution this is the best compromise)